# Range.RemoveDuplicates & Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I try to remove duplicates

```
Set shUpl = Sheets("Upload")
Dim LR as Long 

LR = shUpl.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
shUpl.Range("A1:O" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Header:=xlYes
```

But I have error

> Run-time error '1004':
> Application-defined or object-defined error

I've looked through all articles with same issue but couldn't find a solution

Comment: @BigBen, forgot to tell about

Dim LR as Long
LR = shUpl.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Does Column 10+ (J) have data in it? If the used range doesn't cover 10 indices I get that error.

Comment: @Warcupine, yes, there is data in columns 1:15 and also in 10